# Composition of relations - check my method

Tags: relations, function-and-relation-composition

I just want to check that the method I am using for the composition of relations is right.

If a pair in R (z,y) and a pair in S (x,z) then (x,y) yield and become a pair in SoR?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Easy check is to view the pairs as two things that have to connect to each other

Put them in the order of the relations in the compositions, i.e $S$ pair before $R$ pair:

$(x,z)(z,y)$ Are the two "inner elements" equal? Yes as $z=z$. Then the outer elements $x,y$ form a pair $(x,y)$ in the composition $S \circ R$